# Adding both static and dynamic elements to a Ext-JS List in Sencha Architect

Tags: list, extjs, touch, store, ext.list

I'm using Sencha Architect for developing a Sencha 2 mobile application.  I would like to have a List with two dividers.  One divider would be called "Current Location" and the List element would also say "Current Location" which could be clicked on.  The next header would say, "My Locations" and under that it would be a list populated by a Store called locationStore.

I'm know how to do populate lists from a store, but I'm not sure how to mix both the static elements (header and single list item) with dynamic elements (header and longer list).

I'm reusing this list in several views, so it would be nice if it could somehow be populated from a Store.

Hope someone has two cents on this topic.

Cool.